# Can nullptr be used as a variable argument (varargs)?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, nullptr

Can I use the `nullptr` keyword as an argument for a variable function? If so, does it undergo any kind of standard conversion, and what is the type of the resulting value?

Concretely, is the following correct?

```
std::printf("%p", nullptr);
```

Or does it have to be:

```
std::printf("%p", static_cast<void *>(nullptr));
```

Comment: `nullptr` has the type of `nullptr_t`, no? Any thoughts about conversions should start there.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: I know, but I couldn't find a rule relating that type to the ellipsis. I was looking under standard conversions, and never checked the section on function calls.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain your objections?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> **§5.2.2p7** When there is no parameter for a given argument, the argument is passed in such a way that the receiving function can obtain the value of the argument by invoking `va_arg` (18.10)... An argument that has (possibly cv-qualified) type `std::nullptr_t` is converted to type `void*` (4.10)...

Comment: `+1`, my Standard-fu got a little rusty.

Comment: I *finally* found it and then came back to 6 answers :p

Answer (score 11):

The standard says that any argument of type `nullptr_t` will be converted to `void*` when matching `...`.  So the call is correct without the cast.

EDIT:

From the standard (§5.2.2/7):

> When there is no parameter for a given argument, the argument is
>   passed in such a way that the receiving function can obtain the
>   value of the argument by invoking `va_arg`.  The
>   lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer
>   standard conversions are performed on the argument expression.
>   An argument that has (possibly cv-qualified) type
>   `std::nullptr_t` is converted to type `void*`.